load metadata for docker.io/library/node is stuck
so i have a simple Dockerfile
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./app.js ./

EXPOSE 9999


CMD ["node","app.js"]

and express app and when i try to build the image the
the build command gets stuck at load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14
enter image description here
i tried searching the problem but i didn't anyone with similar problem

Why node 14? I see this is an exercise, but more than one year ago node 14 reached its end of life. Also, a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
